# Persistent data structures: a persistent index?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, functional-programming, lisp

Functional programming utilizes immutable data.  When you modify something you reinstantiate "the world" reusing the previous incarnation in as much as possible for your augmented world.

I am exploring FP in JavaScript.  I have created a List object similar to a List in Lisp.  You `cons` a new head onto an existing tail.  While adding items to the persistent list I want to create a persistent index that coincides with the list.  Thus, if I `cons` a new contact onto a list of contacts, I may want to index last name and phone number so I can locate items quickly without effectively initiating a full table scan.

Q: In JavaScript, what kind of persistent data structure could one build that would provide fast keyed access?

That is, I think the idea is to reuse previous index data in constructing the augmented index.  Short of cloning all the keys on the previous index into the augmented index I am finding this problem mind numbing.  With cloning this would waste an incredible amount of memory while programmatically loading data.  The index should be memory efficient and provide fast access by value.

Comment: It's sad that people close real questions.

Comment: For JS implementations check out "mori" http://swannodette.github.io/mori/
as well as "feat" http://cofylang.org/tests/test-feat.html

Comment: I believe `vectors` from mori.js fits the bill.

Answer (score 3):

You might use some kind of self-balancing binary search tree, just like you might in any other language (although in many languages, such a datastructure is already provided). Each insert costs `O(log n)` on average, including the rebalancing which will create `O(log n)` new search nodes.

One fairly simple datastructure is the [splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree). There's a lovely functional implementation of splay trees in Chris Okasaki's [*Purely Functional Datastructures*](http://books.google.com.pe/books?id=SxPzSTcTalAC). In fact, there are lots of really cool datastructures in that book. Highly recommended. (If you search, you might find Okasaki's thesis online, which has the splay tree implementation, too.)